# udp message with multiple data types using boost

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am new to boost, I want to send a udp packet with multiple data type values. for example I want to send a packet of three bytes, in which first two bytes are used for message code and the last one is used for service id. I've used memcpy for this purpose, but the resultant buffer does not contain correct and desired values. Here is my code.

```
char buff[3];
uint16_t msgCode = 23;
char serviceId = '9';

msgCode = htons(msgCode);

memcpy(buff, &msgCode, 2);
memcpy(buff+2, &serviceId, 1);

std::string data = buff;
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> message(new std::string(data));

sock.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data),dest_endPoint
, boost::bind(&udp_class::handle_send, this, message, boost::asio::placeholders::error
, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Note: I've problems only in the buffer, I mean how to insert values of multiple types into the buffer and send as a udp packet.

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see a problem in the posted code. The `data` variable is a local one and it is passed as the `buffers` parameter of the `async_send_to` method call. The `boost::asio::buffer` class instance does not copy the `data` content. In the moment when Asio sends data the `data` variable is already destroyed. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html) explains this behavior.

> Although the buffers object may be copied as necessary, ownership of
>   the underlying memory blocks is retained by the caller, which must
>   guarantee that they remain valid until the handler is called.

To fix the problem, as far as I understand the code, is necessary to point the `message` variable as the `boost::asio::buffer` constructor parameter.